# Making sulfate from elemental sulfur

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, home-experiment, isotope

I have $\approx\pu{2 g}$ of elemental sulfur that I need to convert to dissolved sulfate in DI water. What's the easiest lab chemistry that will get me there?

Comment: If you convert the whole sample, there is no fractionation. And for doing that, perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid#Manufacture ?

Answer (score 3):

You burn the sulfur and lead the fumes through a solution of $\ce{H2O2}$. Afterwards you boil that solution for a moment to remove the rest of the peroxide.

Use a vertical tube reactor or something so you can lead a soft stream of oxygen gas (or pressurised air, in a pinch) over the sulphur.